Neovim blocks kitty select to copy and click on url to open with mouse
Kitty has configuration like opening a url in browser when it is clicked and copying text selected with a mouse to clipboard automatically. This works on Vim but does not work in Neovim.
How can these features of kitty be used in Neovim?
NVIM v0.9.5

kitty 0.31.0

VIM - Vi IMproved 9.1 (2024 Jan 02, compiled Mar 05 2024 22:43:21)
Compiled by Arch Linux

Kernel: 6.1.85-1-MANJARO


gx opens url in browser and is better than clicking with mouse. source. For context about automatically copying to clipboard, I really like the ability of not copying every yank to os clipboard. set clipboard+=unnamedplus copies everything to clipboard all the time.

Ok so first things first, these aren't "kitty features", these are x11/wayland features where you can copy text by highlighting and paste by middle mouse clicking.
Second of all, nvim sets mouse=a by default. You have a few options here, turn mouse support off, set mouse to r instead to allow copy and pasting via mouse, or hold shift while highlighting so you can still copy and paste.

gx is better than holding shift because it does not require a mouse.
